# Ensure user enter correct data type. c# Console App

Tags: c#

Beginner at C# and working on a Console Application currently. If I say ask the user to type in a date but they type in a string that cannot be converted to a date time how can I ensure they're requested to try again? I know this is easy via an if/else statement but if an application has hundreds of questions like this it does not seem right to have equally hundreds of if statements just to see if the datatype is correct. Is there something in built I've missed or a "hack" to carry out this?

e.g

```
Console.WriteLine("What is your birthday");

Datetime bday = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
```

User enters say "dfio".

Comment: I'd be more worried why your application asks a user hundreds of questions - seem like bad UX design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function like

```
public static int GetInt()
{
    int X;
    String Result = Console.ReadLine();
    while(!Int32.TryParse(Result, out X))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Not a valid Int, try again!");
       Result = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    return X;
}
```

and use it multiple times.

In your case (`DateTime`) you only need to change the code to

```
public static DateTime GetDateTime()
{
    DateTime X;
    String Result = Console.ReadLine();
    while(!DateTime.TryParse(Result, out X))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Not a valid DateTime, try again!");
       Result = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    return X;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool valid = false;
DateTime bday;
while(!valid){
  Console.WriteLine("What is your birthday");
  string input = Console.ReadLine();

  if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out bday))
  { 
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Date");
    valid = true;
  }
}
```

This will loop until a valid DateTime is entered.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation page will help you supply a custom format to the parser.

This is only a solution to this specific input.

Answer (score 0):

Use ToString() method to take input as string.
Datetime bday = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine().ToString());

Comment: [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) already returns a `string` - why would you need to convert it to a `string` again?

Comment: This will throw a FormatException if the string input is in the wrong format, which is exactly the same issue as the question

Comment: yes it does but sometimes we need to explicitly define this method to be precised.

Comment: No, we don't - the [reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tc6ws5s(v=vs.110).aspx) even states: *"Because this method simply returns the current string unchanged, there is no need to call it directly."*

Comment: you will be right, but chose this way when it did not used to work implicitly